# REG EXPORT not working in powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

I am trying to write a simple command to create a .reg file and export the key infos in it, but it just doesn't seem to accept the REG EXPORT command, even if I run it as admin

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Users\operateur\Documents\Configuration.reg"
REG EXPORT "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Groupe ABC", "C:\Users\operateur\Documents\Configuration.reg"
```

Comment: So what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. If you run the commands from the console, you're presented with a confirmation prompt to overwrite the existing file:

```
PS C:\...\regExport>New-Item Configuration.reg


    Directory: C:\Users\keith\Sandbox\regExport


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         12/4/2020   5:26 PM              0 Configuration.reg


PS C:\...\regExport>REG EXPORT "HKLM\SOFTWARE\IrfanView", "Configuration.reg"
File Configuration.reg already exists. Overwrite (Yes/No)?
```

But the same commands just hang in the ISE.

You're actually blocking **`Reg Export`** from creating the file by the unnecessary **`New-Item`** Cmdlet, which creates an empty file of the same name.

```
Either eliminate the **`New-Item`** Cmdlet or use the `/y` switch with the **`Reg Export`** command.

REG EXPORT KeyName FileName [/y] [/reg:32 | /reg:64]

  Keyname    ROOTKEY[\SubKey] (local machine only).
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  FileName   The name of the disk file to export.

  /y       Force overwriting the existing file without prompt.

  /reg:32  Specifies the key should be accessed using the 32-bit registry view.

  /reg:64  Specifies the key should be accessed using the 64-bit registry view.
```